# how to find required terms entries

Tags: sqlite

I want get table entries that mac address is empty while hostname could either match key word A or match key word B.
but below command seems not getting correct answer.
any suggestion ?

```sql
select * from table where mac_address <> \'\' AND hostname LIKE '%A%'  OR hostname LIKE '%C%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have the statement is equivalent to:

```
select * from table 
where (mac_address <> '\' AND hostname LIKE '%A%') OR hostname LIKE '%C%'
```

because the `AND` operator has [precedence](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) over the `OR` operator.
So use parentheses to correct it:

```
select * from table 
where mac_address <> '\' AND (hostname LIKE '%A%'  OR hostname LIKE '%C%')
```

I don't know why you use the backslash before `'\'`. It is not valid in an sql statement.

Comment: Thank you forpas, this is what exactly I want here.